# Which approach is better and faster - Symfony2, Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have some related entities, let's say for convenience `Product` and `Category`. They are related OneToMany and ManyToOne. (each product has one category and one category has many products)

My goal is to display in a template all categories with all their products, but in alphabetical order. For example like this:

Furniture

- Bed
- Sofa
- TV

Meals

- Banana
- Fish
- Lemon

Office

- Paper
- Pen

I want both categories and products to be sorted.

So:

**Approach 1**

Write queries with doctrine to get all categories orderedBy name ASC, and to get all products orderedBy name ASC and then in the template:

```
{% for c in all_categories %}

    {{ c.name }}

    {% for p in all_products %}
        {% if p.category == c %}
            {{ p.name }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

**Approach 2**

Get only the categories no matter how they are ordered. Change fetch to eager. Then write a sort filter as Twig Extension like this:

```
public function sortByName($a, $b)
{
        if($a->getName() === $b->getName()) {
            return 0;
        }
        if($a->getName() < $b->getName()) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 1;       
}
```

and using an iterator and `uasort()` with this function and then in the template:

```
{% for c in all_categories|sortbyname %}

    {{ c.name }}
    {% for p in c.products|sortbyname %}
        {{ p.name }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

What I can see is that in **1** the if check is bad because many checks will be redundant. And getting all products when I already have all categories is also redundant. But I think that sorting with Doctrine should be faster than that with the twig extension. So I can't tell which one should I use. If it matters, in my case, I have 3 entities, like this: Each shop has categories and each category has products.

Can you please help me? Thanks very much in advance! :)

Comment: :$ I guess it came because there is a for loop before the if statement, and the for loop is really a loop :D

Comment: i think for what you're doing, a nested loop is acceptable.. if you're just trying to decided which way, approach 1 is easier to read. what is the point of using a twig ext?

Answer (score 0):

This is more an algo choice rather than a symfony/doctrine issue.

My approach is to get all products sorted by (category-name, product-name), and then loop over them to store them in an array indexed by your category. It can be used if you have many products, and enough memory to load all objects at one, but will be faster ( #nbproducts, and not #nbproducts*#nbcategories ), and will use only one ORM request, that will use indexes to sort data.

Php code would look like this :

```
$sorted_products = array();
foreach ($products as $product) {
  $category = $product->getCategory();
  if (!array_key_exists($category->getId(), $sorted_products)) {
      $sorted_products[$category->getId()] = array('category' => $category, 'products' => array());
  }
  $sorted_products['products'][] = $product;
}
```

And then you just have to do 2 foreach in your twig :

```
{% for category_infos in sorted_products %}
  {{ category_infos.category.name }}
  {% for product in category_infos.products %}
    {{ product.name }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```